# MVVMCross : create a messaging bubble listview style

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I want to create a bubble conversation like with a listview.

For example, take messenger by Facebook.

And my problems are : how to create a MvxItemTemplate for each message (sended and received) ?

When I send a message, I want to use my item_sendedmessage.xml
But when I receive a message, it's my item_receivedmessage.xml

I don't know how to use converted (like Xamarin Forms).

My MessageEntity

```
public class MessageEntity
{
     public string Message { get; set; }
     public bool IsSended { get; set; }
}
```

And my List (RecyclerView)

```
 <MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:MvxBind="ItemsSource Messages"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

When my messageEntity.IsSended = true, I want to use my right itemTemplate with red color, and when it's false, blue and left.

Thanks

EDIT : [Found](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Working%20With%20Collections/Collections.Droid/Views/PolymorphicListItemTypesView.cs) for ListView but not for RecyclerView

EDIT 2 :

item_sendedmessage.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              //NOT WORKING ->
              android:layout_gravity="right"
              //NOT WORKING ->
              android:background="@drawable/sended_message_style"
              android:layout_margin="10dp"  >

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
    app:MvxBind="Text Message">

  </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a new class to your Droid project which implements the `IMvxTemplateSelector` interface. This is a simple interface to implement. In `GetItemLayoutId` you will return the Resource.Layout. depending on the sender of the message. Here is an example:

```
public class MessageItemTemplate : IMvxTemplateSelector
{
    protected const int FromDriver = 0;
    protected const int FromOther = 1;
    protected readonly string DriverEmployeeId;

    public MessageItemTemplate(string driverEmployeeId)
    {
        DriverEmployeeId = driverEmployeeId;
    }

    public int GetItemViewType(object forItemObject)
    {
        var messageModel = forItemObject as MessageModel;
        if (messageModel == null) return FromOther;
        return messageModel.SenderId == DriverEmployeeId ? FromDriver : FromOther;
    }

    public int GetItemLayoutId(int fromViewType)
    {
        switch (fromViewType)
        {
            case FromDriver:
                return Resource.Layout.listitem_message_from_driver;
            default:
                return Resource.Layout.listitem_message_from_peer;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you can associate this template selector with the RecyclerView via code:

```
var mvxRecyclerView = FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.messages_recycler);
if (_mvxRecyclerView != null)
{
    _mvxTemplateSelector = new MessageItemTemplate("TEST");
    _mvxRecyclerView.ItemTemplateSelector = _mvxTemplateSelector;
    var layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this)
    {
        StackFromEnd = true
    };
    _mvxRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}
```

You can control the color using the MvvmCross Color plugin, or just use two different templates like I did in the example code above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it work but my sended messages are in the left gravity and not in the right. Check my original post.

Comment: You could fix that by changing from `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`. Then your `TextView` can change `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` in XML or the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` in code.